# Unable to read a character from the user

Tags: java

I have written the code to create a `LinkList` of characters. So I am inserting characters one by one from the user. But I am only able to insert the character only once.

My code is:

```
import java.io.*;

class Node {
    char a;
    Node next;

    Node(char a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class LinkList {
    static Node start;
    static Node end;

    LinkList() {
        start = null;
        end = null;
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("enter the no. of nodes to be created");

        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        char a;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter the value for the node");
            a = (char) System.in.read();

            Node no = new Node(a);
            insert(no);
        }
        display();
    }


    public static void insert(Node n) {
        if (start == null) {
            start = n;
            end = n;
        } else {
            end.next = n;
            end = n;
        }
    }
}
```

My output is:

```
enter the no. of nodes to be created
6
enter the value for the node
a
enter the value for the node
enter the value for the node
enter the value for the node
m
enter the value for the node
enter the value for the node
a
m
```

Over here I want to enter 6 characters but I am able to enter only 2 of them.
I want to enter all the 6 characters but I am only able to enter 2 characters.(a,m)

Comment: try br.readline instead of System.in.read();

Comment: Guess you are pressing 'enter' in hurry without entering the character...:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `a = (char) System.in.read();` add the following

```
System.in.read();
System.in.read();
```

Why is this?

When you type `a` and press `Enter`,there are 3 characters read.
1 for `a` and 2 for `Enter`.(`\r` and `\n` will be read as character input when you press `Enter`)
So the characters input in 6 iterations as follows:

1. a
2. \r
3. \n
4. m
5. \r
6. \n

So you could only read 2 of the chars you wanted.You can skip storing the \r and \n into you linkedlist by simply reading and not doing anything with it.

Modify `a = (char) System.in.read();` as follows:

```
a = (char) System.in.read();
System.in.read();
System.in.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

`a = (char) System.in.read();`

You are doing this even tho you created a `BufferedReader` before. What you need to do is this:

`a = (char) br.readLine()`

Which is gonna read the whole line. You can't do `read()`, because it's gonna read more characters (like enter and `\r`). But that is not all, you only need a single character from the line so you will have error with this, you need to extract a single character from this line, like this:

`a = (char) br.readLine().charAt(0)`

I think `charAt()` method is self-explanatory. Now it will work alright. I also suggest using `Scanner` for taking user inputs, read about `Scanner` here: [click](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ndale/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Scanner as welll

```
public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the no. of nodes to be created");

    //If input entered was not an integer - exception raised
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    char a;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        System.out.println("enter the value for the node");
        a = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        Node no = new Node(a);
        insert(no);
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to trim console noise by using a prompt without a newline so use `print("xxx")` title printout. Read a line (texts before ENTER newline) and take one character.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Node {
    char a;
    Node next;
    Node(char a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class LinkList {
    static Node start;
    static Node end;

    LinkList() {
        start = null;
        end = null;
    }

    public static void main(String ar[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the no. of nodes to be created: ");

        int n = Integer.parseInt( sc.nextLine().trim() );
        for (int idx=1; idx <= n; idx++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the value for the node: ");
            char a = sc.nextLine().trim().charAt(0);
            Node no = new Node(a);
            insert(no);
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println("Content of list");
        display();
    }

    public static void insert(Node n) {
        if (start == null) {
            start = n;
            end = n;
        } else {
            end.next = n;
            end = n;
        }
    }

    private static void display() {
        Node node = start;
        while(node!=null) {
            System.out.println(node.a);
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

}
```